# How are Linux kernel bugs being tracked?

Tags: linux-kernel, bugs, bugzilla

What an hour of Googling bring out that **mainstream** Linux kernel bugs are being logged in two distinct systems:

### [Mailing list](http://vger.kernel.org/vger-lists.html#linux-kernel)

> This is the Linux kernel development discussion and bug reporting
>   mailing list.

The mailing list is archived by a number of services, *e.g.*

- [Gmane](http://dir.gmane.org/gmane.linux.kernel)
- [lkml](https://lkml.org/lkml)
- [MARC](https://marc.info/?l=linux-kernel)
- [Mail archive](http://www.mail-archive.com/linux-kernel@vger.kernel.org)
- [Indiana](http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel)

### [Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.kernel.org)

> This is the Kernel Tracker system (based on Bugzilla) for posting bugs
>   against the mainline Linux kernels (not distribution kernels).

Distributions, *e.g.* Ubuntu have their own [bug tracker](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Bugs) which may be set to track upstream bugs.

I wonder that,

- Are the bugs reported on the either of the services synced back to the other?
- Assuming that the mailing list and the bugzilla are not mirrors of each other (*i.e.* those are independent and bugs are *not* synced), how do Linux developers coordinate between the bugs reported across services?
- Isn't it inconvenient to refer to the bugs reported to mailing list later on due to not having any bug ID? (I understand that one can refer by a mailing archive URL, however doesn't look professional IMO)
- Should a new bug be reported to any one of the services or both?

Answer (score -1):

This is really a very very partial answer, but at least in the netdev mailing list (for the networking subsystem), there are sometimes messages about bugs reported in bugzilla; these messages are sent to the netdev mailing list, with cc to potential owners of the code, for example:
http://www.spinics.net/lists/netdev/msg351687.html